# how to get axis limit from existing plot?

Tags: python, seaborn

If I already make a plot, how to get axis limit from the existing plot so I can make some change for example, increase max limit by 10% etc?

for example, if I use seaborn lmplot and regplot like below. Thanks

```
sns.lmplot(x=x,y=y,data=data,fit_reg=False,legend=False,height=8, aspect=1.7, scatter_kws={"s": 200})
g=sns.regplot(x=x,y=y,data=data,ci=ci,scatter_kws={"s": 200,'alpha':0.1}, 
                     line_kws={'color':'green'})
```

Thanks

Comment: `g.get_xlim()` but `regplot` returns an `matplotlib.axes`, so it should be `ax = sns.regplot(...)` and `ax.get_xlim()`. `g = ` is used plots that return a seaborn FacetGrid

Comment: Thank you Trenton, it works, here is what I did, x_range=g.get_xlim(), g.set_xlim([x_range[0],x_range[1]*1.1])